# VB.NET 2012: Opening a .exe in a folder with Wildcard

Tags: vb.net, exe

I want to open a file inside a directory which has the name of something like: "file_1.8.9.exe". It won't always have the last 3 numbers the same though, so I wanted to have a wildcard to open it that I thought would look something like:

Process.Start("*.exe")

or

Process.Start("File*")

The file will always be the only .exe inside the directory so it is not a problem to open all .exes. I've tried other ways of doing this but I couldn't get any to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Try
            Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\YOUR_DIRECTORY", "file_*.exe")
            Dim dir As String
            For Each dir In dirs
                Process.Start(dir)
            Next
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
        End Try
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, although apparently I had to do a little bit of bug checking on my side first :s